# Reading in a text file from a jar in Jython

Tags: jar, jython

I have a Jython code base and several text files in a jar archive. I am using a script to pack them all into one jar file for easy distribution. I would like to be able to read the text files from within the jar file. I have tried the import statement the command:

fin = java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream('path to the text file inside the jar')

and it says 2 arguments are expected instead of 1 for the getResourceAsStream method. I have searched quite a bit but have not found a clear way to do this using Jython. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking `getResourceAsStream()` on the class, not an instance. That's why there is an error message.

If you first create a classloader object and then use `getResourceAsStream()` on that object, it should work. Something like this:

```jython
from java.lang import ClassLoader
from java.io import InputStreamReader, BufferedReader

loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("org/python/version.properties")
reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))

line = reader.readLine()
while line is not None:
    print line
    line = reader.readLine()
```

Output:

```
# Jython version information
jython.version=2.5.3
jython.major_version=2
jython.minor_version=5
jython.micro_version=3
jython.release_level=15
jython.release_serial=0
jython.build.date=Aug 13 2012
jython.build.time=14:48:36
jython.build.hg_branch=2.5
jython.build.hg_tag=
jython.build.hg_version=c56500f08d34+
```

The output shows the contents of the **org/python/version.properties** file inside **jython.jar** (which is on the classpath when the program runs).

Answer (score 3):

Jars are simply zip files so you can use `zipfile` module. There is my example of reading version info from manifest file:

```
def get_ver(jar_file):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'r')
    try:
        lst = zf.infolist()
        for zi in lst:
            fn = zi.filename
            if fn.lower().endswith('manifest.mf'):
                try:
                    manifest_txt = str(zf.read(zi.filename), encoding='utf8')
                except TypeError:
                    manifest_txt = zf.read(zi.filename)
                lines = manifest_txt.split('\n')
                for line in lines:
                    if 'Implementation-Version:' in line:
                        return line[23:].strip()
    finally:
        zf.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. I am aware that one can unzip the jar file to read in the files. Do you know of a way to read the text files directly from the jar? When searching for this with pure java, there seems to be a getResourceAsStream function which can do this, but I can not figure out how to use it in Jython.

Comment: There is `zipfile.read()`, use it like `fin = zf.read('path to the text file inside the jar')`, example: `content = zf.read('META-INF/MANIFEST.MF')`. This solution works with all Python interpreters, while solution using `getResourceAsStream()` will work only with Jython. But for zipfile you must know name of .jar file, while `getResourceAsStream()` probably can search in jars from CLASSPATH.